# Prove that there are infinitely many primes $P$, such that $3P+2$ and $\frac{3P+1}{2}$ are also primes

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

Prove that there are infinitely many primes $P$, such that $3P+2$ and $\frac{3P+1}{2}$ are also primes. Something possible to do?

Comment: You can show there are [Infinitely many primes of the form $3k+2$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1621324/infinitely-many-primes-of-the-form-3k2) when $k$ is any integer. However the statement you want to prove is very likely unknown (see e.g. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/911690/are-there-infinite-many-primes-p-such-that-2p-1-is-also-prime).

Comment: The first few such primes are $$3,7,19,59,127,167,239,439,479,607,859,967,1039,1259,1427,1559,1567,1699,1879,1979$$ but this sequence is not in [OEIS](https://oeis.org/search?q=3%2C7%2C19%2C59%2C127%2C167%2C239%2C439%2C479%2C607%2C859%2C967%2C1039%2C1259%2C1427). It's the intersection of  https://oeis.org/A023208 and https://oeis.org/A158709.

Comment: How did you get those sequence?

Comment: This has been an unsolved problem for nearly $200$ years. So you should not expect a solution in the next few hours.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(3P+1)/2 would be a special Sophie Germain prime, which is a prime p and 2p+1 is also a prime.
It is not known if there exist infinitely many Sophie Germain primes.
Therefore it is not known if there exist infintely many P.